# Cannot open company file when a different user already has it open

Tags: quickbooks

We had QuickBooks Pro 3-license working perfectly, configured with a server hosting the company file, and 2 workstations sharing in multi-user mode.

But now, neither of the workstations can open the company file if the server already has it open.  If the server closes the file, then they can open it.

Error message suggests checking firewall and Security Essentials.  Disabled both of those, but made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More then a week earlier, we had installed OpenVPN on the server which is hosting the company file (unrelated project).

What I found was that the workstations were attempting a TCP connection to the server - using the wrong IP address.  The IP address they were using was from the private (10.x.x.x) network assigned to the QB file server by the OpenVPN server it was connected to.

The 2 workstations do not have OpenVPN installed, and have no access to this network.

How the private address got communicated to the workstations is a mystery.  Via the company file?

Why it took over a week for the problem to surface after installing OpenVPN is also a mystery.

We have had to abandon the OpenVPN project because of this.  But we'd love to know how QuickBooks file server can co-exist with OpenVPN.